# GitHub Actions not finding cache when using container

Tags: docker, caching, github-actions

I have a GitHub action which builds some software. I have it set to cache one of the tools it builds to save time on subsequent runs, and it works great.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      # installs the apt packages from a cache, speeding up the process substantially
      - name: Install Compiler
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y binutils-arm-none-eabi gcc-arm-none-eabi

      - name: Cache Tools
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: tools
        with:
          path: |
            tools/agbcc
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-tools


      # build and install agbcc into the tools directory
      - name: Clone agbcc
        if: steps.tools.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          path: 'tmp/agbcc'
          repository: 'pret/agbcc'

      - name: Build agbcc
        if: steps.tools.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          ./build.sh
          ./install.sh $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
        working-directory: tmp/agbcc
```

I created a second action with the exact same .yml, the one difference being that it runs inside a container. The only difference to the .yml is the addition of `container: devkitpro/devkitarm:latest`. This is running on the same branch.

For some reason, the container action can't find my cache and I have no idea why. It runs on the same branch so it should be in scope, it's running on the same OS, and for all I can figure out it should be able to see the cache. However, it doesn't find it.

Is this possible to resolve, or is it a limitation of the cache action preventing it from working if you're running inside a container?

Comment: AFAIK, containers are ephemeral and anything installed/cached inside them is going to be destroyed when they exit. One possible solution could be to build your own image with that tool installed on it so you don't have to cache it at all. Or, another alternative could be to cache it on the host and mount that directory when you need it inside the container. You need to test these alternatives on your side.

Comment: This is specifically using the official cache action, which can be recalled between runs of an action.

Comment: How did you try to run it with `container`? With `container: image: devkitpro/devkitarm:latest`, I'm getting `gcc` is not found error. Please include your exact workflow where only the cache was the issue along with screenshots of the workflow with expanded caching steps.

Comment: Huh, I actually have no idea.
The workflow installs `gcc-arm-none-eabi` anyway, so it should be able to compile. All I did was add `container: devkitpro/devkitarm:latest` directly below the `runs-on` key.